# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Mozilla Firefox' executable may have wrong permissions while using GeckoDriver

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I've had some trouble trying to get selenium to do stuff with browsers. 
I'm a super-beginner at this type of stuff, but I still searched, and the most pertinent response I found was that I needed to run the Application as administrator, but it didn't change anything. Here's my code and the error message. Thanks alot.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox")
```

My error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Axel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\Axel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Axel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Axel\Desktop\PYTHON\code.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox")
  File "C:\Users\Axel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 160, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\Axel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 88, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Mozilla Firefox' executable may have wrong permissions.
```

I'm pretty sure these two errors are just one, and I've gone through a  whole bunch of threads, but i never properly understand things. I wondered if it had something to do with geckdriver (which i havem't and don't know how to install.)
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Mozilla Firefox' executable may have wrong permissions.
```

...implies that the **Mozilla Firefox** executable was unaccessable due to wrong permissions.

While working with *Selenium v3.x*, *GeckoDriver* and *Firefox* you have to consider certain facts as follows:

- Instead of *Mozilla Firefox* binary (i.e. `firefox.exe`) you need to pass the *absolute path* of the **GeckoDriver** binary through the *argument* **`executable_path`** within *single quotes* (i.e. `''`) along with the raw (`r`) switch.
- You need to download the latest release of *GeckoDriver* from [this link](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and  ensure that **GeckoDriver** have required permissions to be accessed by **non-root** user.
- Always execute your *TestCases*/*TestSuite* as a **non-root** user.
- Your effective code block will be as follows:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that for Firefox version (47.0 +) you need to use geckodriver. Check it out here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases