# Why can't i open chrome with selenium?

Tags: python

I want to use selenium.webdriver to do anything, but my program doesnt seem to work

I think the problem is with the path in the script, but i am not sure because I literaly copied the text from the file path

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/Users/Rafa/Documents/Python Projects/Firefox')
firefox.get('http://google.com.br/')
```

I want it to open google in firefox (any browser would serve, people recomended ,e firefox)

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Firefox' executable may have wrong permissions.
```

Comment: you can't open Chrome if you use Firefox(). To use Firefox you don't need path to firefox but to [gecodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) which will control Firefox.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50767308/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-mozilla-firefox-execut

Comment: For Chrome you will need [chromedriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/)

Answer (score 1):

In initializing your webdriver you don't use the `firefox` browser or `google` browser.

You need to use their respective drivers to allow an automation software to control it.

`gecodriver` for `firefox`

`chromium` driver for `google chrome`

Check their versions too for it to work.

Good luck :))